# Mod Rewrite Ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm a bit in trouble with  mod rewrite and ubuntu.  I have a website with this htaccess condition :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

My mod rewrite is enabled on kubuntu and I'm working on php 5.6. My site.conf is this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin votre-mail@monsite1.fr
ServerName www.mydomain.localhost
ServerAlias www.mydomain.localhost

DocumentRoot /var/my/root/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

NOTE : this htaccess file works on windows (WAMP) and on my public server. I just won't work on my local environment.

Does someone know what is wrong ? The aim of my condition is to remove the '.php' in the url. Instead, I get 404 errors.

Comment: if you phpinfo(); do you see 'mod_rewrite' is enabled?

Comment: did you restart your apache server once you enabled it?

Comment: HI ! Yes mod_rewite is loaded and I already restarted apache2